# Specifying hard coded input data for D3 Multi-Series Line Chart

Tags: jquery, d3.js

I'm looking at the example for the multi series line chart [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955).

I don't want to use a TSV file and want use a hard coded array. Here's what I'm using right now and it fails to plot the actual data:

```
 var data = [
  [{"date": "20111001", "New York": "63"} , {"date": "20111002", "New York": "60"}],
  [{"date": "20111001", "San Francisco" : "64"} , {"date": "20111001", "San Francisco" : "62"}]
    ];
```

For the sake of simplicity, I have removed the additional city as specified in the example.

Comment: Try console logging the tsv data and looking at its structure, then compare that to your hard coded data structure.  Also, if you could post your code in a fiddle it would help direct answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your array representation. It should be like this - check the [docs](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV):

```
var data = [
   {"date": "20111001", "New York": "63", "San Francisco" : "64"}, 
   {"date": "20111002", "New York": "60", "San Francisco" : "62"},
   {"date": "20111003", "New York": "50", "San Francisco" : "52"},
   {"date": "20111004", "New York": "55", "San Francisco" : "57"},
   {"date": "20111005", "New York": "62", "San Francisco" : "64"},
   {"date": "20111006", "New York": "52", "San Francisco" : "55"}
];
```

Here is the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ndk7A/).